# Is my email address unprofessional?

Tags: email

My email address is '{initials}.{first name}@gmail.com'.

I created this when I was 15 and have used it through high school and 2 years of college. I sent an email to a friend the other day and he pointed out that I should change it because it is unprofessional and 'weird'.

I'll be applying for jobs soon and would like to know if what an email address really makes a difference. Would it give a bad first impression to an employer? Should I make a new one before it is too late?

Comment: i use my firstname.lastname@... and no one has ever commented on my e-mail. Unless your initials + name spell something weird then your friend is completely out of line.

Comment: If you can pick up a domain with your name and use that. But I can't imagine a situation in which an employer is going to care as long as it's not heroinrulezzz@gmail.com

Comment: I'd say your friend is "weird". Unless your initials spell something silly or offensive, there's nothing wrong with this at all.

Comment: Too subjective to give a definitive answer but I'd stick with conservative/professional for an e-mail address unless your professional experience tells you otherwise e.g. for some kind of creative job.

Comment: What about it was claimed to be unprofessional?

Comment: @Brandin I think he called it unprofessional since it didn't contain my full name. It isn't obvious that the first two letters are my initials.

Comment: @uncertainty_principle If it isn't obvious, maybe that would be a reason to change it. Not because it's "unprofessional", but if it's obvious then it's better.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: I think it'd depend on the initials. An email "brb.brian@gmail.com" might read like the guy has a nickname "BRB Brian" and that would look a bit cheap in the professional environment. But if he's actually called "Brian Robert Bell" then that's not his fault. (More examples: red.robert@gmail.com, ppk.peter@gmail.com, tim.tom@gmail.com, jpm.jack@gmail.com) Either way I think "firstname.lastname@gmail.com" is the safest bet.

Comment: The look of unprofessionality can be caused by the "gmail" part, that is, by using a free account instead of a more professional domain. The email being initials+first name is not uncommon. Some companies use {first name}@{company name}.com by default. It is less formal than using last names but it's still professional anyway.